# Java replaceAll with restrictions

Tags: java, regex

I have a text, for example

```
"IssueDetail":"IQR: ON THE FORM YOU MARKED YES TO THE FOLLOWING QUESTION: Anything preventing you from completing the inspection? YOU NEED TO MARK "NO" ON THIS PART. FURTHER DOWN THERE IS A QUESTION THAT STATES : Do you have interior access to complete the inspection? THIS IS WHERE YOU ARE GOING TO CHECK "NO" AND UPLOAD THE PHOTO. PLEASE COMPLETE THIS ON THE FORM AND FOLLOW THE REST OF THE PROMPTS TO COMPLETE THE FULL EXTERIOR INSPECTION. IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS PLEASE CONTACT YOUR VC. THANK YOU! ","PhotoIssue":true,"FormIssue":true,"SendEmail":true
```

In this text I need replace **"** with **\"**

In simple case it can be done using

```
result = string.replaceAll("\"", "\\\"");
```

But I have an restrictions:

- **"** must not be replaced in the very beginning or very end (if **"** is first or last element);
- **"** must not be replaced in instruction **":"**
- **"** must not be replaced in instruction **","**

I can solve it using next steps: split string, replace, concatenate...
I know it also can be solved using regular expression - better way.

But unfortunately I can not build correspond pattern with the restrictions...

In result my example should be (***"NO" - \"NO\"***):

```
"IssueDetail":"IQR: ON THE FORM YOU MARKED YES TO THE FOLLOWING QUESTION: Anything preventing you from completing the inspection? YOU NEED TO MARK \"NO\" ON THIS PART. FURTHER DOWN THERE IS A QUESTION THAT STATES : Do you have interior access to complete the inspection? THIS IS WHERE YOU ARE GOING TO CHECK \"NO\" AND UPLOAD THE PHOTO. PLEASE COMPLETE THIS ON THE FORM AND FOLLOW THE REST OF THE PROMPTS TO COMPLETE THE FULL EXTERIOR INSPECTION. IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS PLEASE CONTACT YOUR VC. THANK YOU! ","PhotoIssue":true,"FormIssue":true,"SendEmail":true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is the following (using lookarounds):

```
//               | not preceded by beginning of string or : or ,
//               |        | escaped "
//               |        | | not followed by : or , or end of string
test.replaceAll("(?<!^|:|,)\"(?!:|,|$)", "\\\\\"")
```

**Example**

```
String test = "\"IssueDetail\":\"IQR: ON THE FORM YOU MARKED YES TO THE FOLLOWING QUESTION: "
+ "Anything preventing you from completing the inspection? YOU NEED TO MARK \"NO\" "
+ "ON THIS PART. FURTHER DOWN THERE IS A QUESTION THAT STATES : Do you have "
+ "interior access to complete the inspection? THIS IS WHERE YOU ARE GOING TO "
+ "CHECK \"NO\" AND UPLOAD THE PHOTO. PLEASE COMPLETE THIS ON THE FORM AND "
+ "FOLLOW THE REST OF THE PROMPTS TO COMPLETE THE FULL EXTERIOR INSPECTION. "
+ "IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS PLEASE CONTACT YOUR VC. THANK YOU! "
+ "\",\"PhotoIssue\":true,\"FormIssue\":true,\"SendEmail\":true";

System.out.println(
    test.replaceAll("(?<!^|:|,)\"(?!:|,|$)", "\\\\\"")
);
```

**Output** (added line breaks for clarity)

```
"IssueDetail":"IQR: ON THE FORM YOU MARKED YES TO THE FOLLOWING QUESTION: 
Anything preventing you from completing the inspection? YOU NEED TO MARK \"NO\" 
ON THIS PART. FURTHER DOWN THERE IS A QUESTION THAT STATES : Do you have interior 
access to complete the inspection? THIS IS WHERE YOU ARE GOING TO CHECK \"NO\" 
AND UPLOAD THE PHOTO. PLEASE COMPLETE THIS ON THE FORM AND FOLLOW THE REST OF 
THE PROMPTS TO COMPLETE THE FULL EXTERIOR INSPECTION. IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS 
PLEASE CONTACT YOUR VC. THANK YOU! ","PhotoIssue":true,"FormIssue":true,
"SendEmail":true
```

**Note**

See the Java pattern [doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for additional insights on look-arounds.

Comment: Mena, Can you explain please how does work the part *?<!^* of your expression?

Comment: @Sergii this is a negative look-behind. It looks before the actual symbols (`^` represents the input's beginning, `|` an OR operator and `:` and `,` are just literals), before the consumed literal `"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookeahed and lookbehind.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "\"IssueDetail\":\"IQR: ON THE FORM YOU MARKED YES TO THE FOLLOWING QUESTION: Anything preventing you "
            + "from completing the inspection? YOU NEED TO MARK \"NO\" ON THIS PART. FURTHER DOWN THERE IS A QUESTION THAT STATES : "
            + "Do you have interior access to complete the inspection? THIS IS WHERE YOU ARE GOING TO CHECK \"NO\" "
            + "AND UPLOAD THE PHOTO. PLEASE COMPLETE THIS ON THE FORM AND FOLLOW THE REST OF THE PROMPTS TO COMPLETE "
            + "THE FULL EXTERIOR INSPECTION. IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS PLEASE CONTACT YOUR VC. THANK YOU! \",\"PhotoIssue\":"
            + "true,\"FormIssue\":true,\"SendEmail\":true";

    String p = s.replaceAll("(?<![,:])\"(?![,:])", "\\\"");

    String expected = "\"IssueDetail\":\"IQR: ON THE FORM YOU MARKED YES TO THE FOLLOWING QUESTION: "
            + "Anything preventing you from completing the inspection? YOU NEED TO MARK \"NO\" ON THIS PART. FURTHER DOWN THERE"
            + " IS A QUESTION THAT STATES : Do you have interior access to complete the inspection? "
            + "THIS IS WHERE YOU ARE GOING TO CHECK \"NO\" AND UPLOAD THE PHOTO. "
            + "PLEASE COMPLETE THIS ON THE FORM AND FOLLOW THE REST OF THE PROMPTS TO COMPLETE THE FULL EXTERIOR INSPECTION."
            + " IF YOU HAVE ANY QUESTIONS PLEASE CONTACT YOUR VC. THANK YOU! \",\"PhotoIssue\":true,\"FormIssue\":true,\"SendEmail\":true";

    System.out.println(p.equals(expected));
}
```

O/P :

```
true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `string.replaceAll("(\\w|\\s)(\")(\\w|\\s)", "$1\\\\$2$3");`

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.